# Java code for unzip 7z file with password

Tags: java, compression, unzip, 7zip

I have tried to unzip the 7z file in Java code but I'm getting "Bad 7z signature"

Any suggestions would be helpful..

I've used UTF-16LE and UTF-16 both throwing same error

Below is the code that Ive tried
*----*----+++-

public void SevenZFile(String directory, String encryptCompressFileName, String password) {

```
    SevenZFile sevenZFile = null;
    SevenZArchiveEntry entry = null;

    try {

        File file = new File(directory+encryptCompressFileName);
        byte[] inputData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        fis.read(inputData);
        fis.close();

        // SeekableInMemoryByteChannel inMemoryByteChannel = new SeekableInMemoryByteChannel(inputData);
        if(null != password){
            byte[] pass = password.getBytes("UTF16");
            sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(file, pass);
        }else{
            sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(file);
        }

        // Go through all entries
        while (null != (entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry())) {

            // Maybe filter by name. Name can contain a path.
            String processingFileName = entry.getName();
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Found directory entry %s", processingFileName));

            } else {

                // If this is a file, we read the file content into a ByteArrayOutputStream ...
                System.out.println(String.format("Unpacking start %s ...", processingFileName));
                ByteArrayOutputStream contentBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                // ... using a small buffer byte array.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = sevenZFile.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    contentBytes.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }


             FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(directory+processingFileName);
                    fileOut.write(contentBytes.toByteArray());
                    fileOut.flush();
                    wb.write(fileOut);
                    fileOut.close();
                    wb.close();
                }else{ //regular file
                    System.out.println(contentBytes.toString("UTF-8"));
                }
                System.out.println(String.format("Unpacking finish %s ...", processingFileName));   
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            sevenZFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `char[] pass = password.toCharArray();`

Comment: Only accepting byte for file

Comment: Using an old version? That came in 1.17

Answer (score 0):

You asked for,

> Unzipping 7z files with password.

One practice to so is to use [Apache Compress Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/), i recommand to use [try, catch with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to automatically close streams.

```
public static void unzip(File file, String password) throws IOException {
    try (SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(file, password.getBytes())) {
        SevenZArchiveEntry archive = null;
        while ((archive = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (archive.isDirectory()) continue;
            File outputFile = new File(archive.getName());
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
                sevenZFile.transferTo(outputStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally i used `transferTo()` method of the `SevenZFile` object to copy the contents of the entry directly to the output stream, instead of reading and writing the contents byte-by-byte, its more efficient and faster,

Comment: Err, except `transferTo` won't work on that class. It would have to be `sevenZFile.getInputStream(archive).transferTo(outputStream);` But the code will fail anyway with a tree depth of anything other than 1, as no directories are created anywhere. Having said that, the original problem seemed to be password-oriented. Using `getBytes` is far more potentially problematic from a character encoding point of view

Comment: You guys know how to parse password only to the files inside the 7z folder and not to the 7z folder and do extraction? I am able to extract only if the 7z folder is password protected.. I am looking for a Java code that can accept the password to the files inside 7z folder.